# Django annotation in a loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an unknown amount of columns with annotate:

```
def add_daily_usage_record(query, days):

   for i in days:
       query.annotate('day_' + i + '_usage'= "doesn't matter"
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to give an annotation a name without writing it? or maybe if I have the name of the new column in a variable, is it possible to pass it to annotate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dict` unpacking with the `**` operator to provide dynamic keyword arguments to any function and you should probably reassign the query:

```
query = query.annotate(**{'day_' + i + '_usage': "doesn't matter"})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do an annotation or other operation on a queryset, it returns a new instance of the queryset.  It doesn't modify the previous queryset.

So change your statement in the loop to

```
query = query.annotate(...)
```